# Convert a list of objects to a map of key and list of objects in java 8

Tags: java-8

I want to convert a List to a map of  where the key is continent name and value is a list of students in each continent.

I have seen quite a few posts on stackoverflow but they were not giving me enough hints on how to go about it.

I have an internal map that specified the nationality <-> continent mapping

```
Hashmap<String,String> continentNationalityMap = new HashMap<>();
continentNationalityMap.put("USA", "North America");
continentNationalityMap.put("British", "Europe");
continentNationalityMap.put("Japan", "Asia");
continentNationalityMap.put("China", "Asia");
continentNationalityMap.put("Portugal", "Europe");
```

My student class is as below,

```
class Student{
   String name;
   String nationality;
   int age;
}
```

What is the best way to convert this in java 8 using streams?
Should I just do the lookup in map function and put it in a pre constructed map or is there a better way to do this with collectors?

Comment: I need a Map<K, List<V>> @Amit

Comment: you should have been more specific. `What is the best way to convert this` is unclear statement. Convert to **what**?